# The bot does not make any sounds, but joins the voice channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

When I enter the command the bot joins the voice channel but doesn't make any sounds, what could be wrong?

```
import discord
import os
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

key = "MTA3ODgwODI5NjgyNTI5NDkzOA.GiyFb-.35Pr2R3v3EfqGQZSaYhBrU-8uGbjLUIhZODhLc"
prefix = "!"
voice_clients = {}

yt_dl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opts)

ffmpeg_options = {'options': "-vn"}

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.voice_states = True

client = commands.Bot(prefix, intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"GOTOVO KAPITAN{client.user}")


@client.event
async def on_message (msg):
    if msg.content.startswith("?play"):
        try:
            voice_clients = await msg.author.voice.channel.connect() 
            voice_clients[voice_clients.guild.id] = voice_clients

            url = msg.content.split()[1]

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False) )

            song = data['url']
            player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, **ffmpeg_options, executable="C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe")

            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].play(player)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    if msg.content.startswith("?pause"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].pause()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    if msg.content.startswith("?resume"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].resume()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
if msg.content.startswich("?stop"):
        try:
            voice_clients[msg.guild.id].stop()
            await voice_clients[msg.guild.id].disconnect()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

# Bot Online?
@client.command()
async def boted(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f' Bot Online! ')

client.run(key)
```

I looked at quite a lot of similar situations on many forums, but I still did not understand why this happens and how to solve it, on the video from which I read this code, everything works out and I rewrote it several times. (I'm new to Python, so sorry if this is too easy a mistake)